# How to upgrade sphinx?

Tags: 16.04, python

From the output of `sphinx-build --version` I see I have:

> Sphinx (sphinx-build) 1.6.3

How do I upgrade to the latest version, which I believe to currently be 
1.8?

I have tried `apt install python3-sphinx` and `pip install`, but that alone does not seem to change the version I get when running `sphinx-build`.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 but I hope this helps people with newer versions as well! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can install Sphinx directly from a clone of the Git repository or simply installing directly via pip pointing git repository url.

```
git clone https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx
cd sphinx
pip install .
```

or

```
pip install git+https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx
```

If you use python3.

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx
```

Comment: If that worked, my plain `pip install` would have already solved the issue... would it not?

Comment: I tried and here is output 
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ sphinx-build --version
Sphinx (sphinx-build) 1.6.7

Comment: I ran `pip install git+https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx` but still get the same version when I run `sphinx-build --version`. Did this solve your issue @KetanPatel?

Comment: It looks like you did not remove previous version completely and still present in system.

Answer (score 0):

Remove old installation and then make sure to use python3 and pip3 (set alias for python and pip to python3 and pip3 respectively) and then pip install sphinx.